# How reduce the size of the legend to fit in the figure or shift it to the top left?

Tags: r

I am trying to draw a bar plot but the legend is on the top right and it is shadowed by the bar plots. How shall I move the legend to the topleft or reduce its size to fit it properly in the right top side. Below is the code and the picture.

```
M<-read.delim("~/Desktop/sample.txt",row.names="Methods")
M<-as.matrix(M)
barplot(M, main="Obs by different methods at different replicates",
     xlab="Number of observations", col=c("darkblue","red","green","yellow"),ylab="Number of stages",
    legend = rownames(M), beside=TRUE)
```

How shall I change the code to fit it properly ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a specific call to the `legend()` function to move it to the `'topleft'` corner. For example:

```
M<-read.delim("~/Desktop/sample.txt",row.names="Methods")
M<-as.matrix(M)
barplot(M, main="Obs by different methods at different replicates",
 xlab="Number of observations", col=c("darkblue","red","green","yellow"),ylab="Number of stages", beside=TRUE)
legend('topleft', rownames(M), fill=c("darkblue","red","green","yellow"))
```

Does this help?

Otherwise, you can also play with other parameters of the legend, for example putting a `cex=` inside its call. I will let you discover them by typing `?legend` in the R console.

Answer (score 1):

`barplot()` adds a legend by calling the `legend()` function, which is extremely flexible and allows you to specify exactly where a legend should be drawn by providing either `x` and `y` coordinates or a descriptive keyword (check out `?legend` for details).

You can call `legend()` directly:

```
barplot(VADeaths, beside = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 100), col = 1:5)
legend("topleft", legend = rownames(VADeaths), fill = 1:5)
```

Or pass arguments to `legend()` via `barplot()`:

```
barplot(VADeaths, beside = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 100),
    legend.text = rownames(VADeaths), 
    args.legend = list(x = "topleft"))
```